# calcular media de uma lista linha por linha no python

Tags: python, lista

pergunta:
Usando o arquivo texto notas_estudantes.dat escreva um programa que calcula a média das notas de cada estudante e imprime o nome e a média de cada estudante.
arquivo:

```
jose 10 15 20 30 40
pedro 23 16 19 22
suzana 8 22 17 14 32 17 24 21 2 9 11 17
gisela 12 28 21 45 26 10
joao 14 32 25 16 89
```

usei o seguinte codigo:

```
arq=open('notas_estudantes.dat','r')
conteudo=arq.readlines()
arq.close()
soma=0
for item in conteudo:
    nom=item.split()
    for x in nom[1:300]:
        soma+=int(x)
    print(nom[0],':',soma/(len(nom)-1))
```

o problema que ele soma as notas da primeira linha e divide certo mas ele soma mais a segunda e assim por diante, nao estou sabendo como fazer para ele somar linha por linha e dividir de forma correta. 
ficando assim:

```
jose : 23
pedro : 48.75
suzana : 32.416666666666664
gisela : 88.5
joao : 141.4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simples: mova a linha de código `soma=0` para depois do seu laço `for`. Assim:

```
arq=open('notas_estudantes.dat','r')
conteudo=arq.readlines()
arq.close()
for item in conteudo:
    soma=0
    nom=item.split()
    for x in nom[1:300]:
        soma+=int(x)
    print(nom[0],':',soma/(len(nom)-1))
```

Assim, ele só vai acumular o valor para cada "item" (ou seja, para cada aluno), reiniciando em 0 no próximo item.

Comment: nossa que facil... xD Muito obrigado